# Azure WCF Service: csdef file vs app.config

Tags: azure, wcf

I just created a new Azure WCF Service project in Visual Studio. Visual Studio added both: a csedf config file and a app.config file.

Why there are two files? Which file should I use to configure the wcf endpoints? In the default project the 'behaviors' are stored in the app.config and the endpoint settings in the csedf file. Why not both in one file? Where is the difference? What should I configure in which file?

Answer (score 0):

Csdef is the layout of your cscfg file. Everything defined in csdef should have its corresponding value in cscfg. Its like a breakdown of app.config into two. One is definition and other is configuration. 
The benifit of this approach is that if your cscfg donot contain the value of tag defined in csdef, it will throw an error on build.